# Как перенести requests session из Requests в Selenium?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, selenium, requests, сессия

Мне нужно авторизоваться в ВК. Для этого использую библиотеку vk_api, после чего получаю сессию

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('number', 'password')
vk_session.auth()
s = vk_session.http
```

Далее мне нужно сделать некоторые действия при помощи Selenium. Вопрос: как перенести эту сессию с сохранением авторизации туда?

Я пробовал переносить по отдельности cookie, но после этого получал `Сайт login.vk.com выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.`

Answer (score 0):

- получаем куки из vk_session.
- запускаем selenium.
- переходим на целевую страницу
  это нужно так как селениум непозволит установить куки для другой страницы.
- ставим куки
  [selenium add_cookie](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/18681a6c1b59434f2639c2c56383a58f1118f009/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L880=)

.

```
driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar'})

driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar', 'path' : '/'})

driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar', 'path' : '/', 'secure':True})
```

- перезагружаем страницу

Я написал [расширение](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/selenium-helper/), которое должно помочь. Как его использовать описано в [статье](https://alexandrsokolov-41020.medium.com/python-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-selenium-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-d75984dc0a38), там же есть и ссылка на гитхаб с примером.